# Android NDK: Resolve dynamic library version conflict

Tags: android, android-ndk, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I'm making an Android app with help of the NDK. One of the shared libraries I'm using depends on ICU, which is another library that I'm trying to explicitly include too.

The problem is that my device (like apparently many others) has an old version of ICU pre-installed. This means that whenever I try to load my shared library, the system tries to load the system version instead of my own, more recent version.

Android seems to ignore any RPATHs, which would otherwise let libraries specific where to look for dependencies. As far as I understand RPATH is essentially hard-coded to `/vendor/lib` and `/system/lib` on Android.

I've seen a few workarounds for the issue, but none of them seem to work:

1. Explicitly load all the libraries (including dependencies) in dependency order.

Although the ICU libraries appear to load fine (via their absolute paths), I still get a `cannot locate symbol` error when attempting to load my shared library. I've quadruple-checked (via `nm` and `readelf`) that the missing symbol does exist in my (newly-compiled) ICU `.so` files.

2. Change the `SONAME` of the ICU dynamic libs to something project-specific and depend on them instead.

This would possibly work, but is kind of a last result because it would involve recompiling a lot of library code with non-trivial dependencies. It also feels more like a hack. A simple name change of the libraries doesn't work for the same reason as 1. – although the ICU symbols get loaded, they are not recognised when the dependent library tries to access them.

My question is to anyone who has tried something like this before or knows their way around linking a bit more than I do: how did you get it working? Is there a way to force Android to get its proverbial hotsauce together and actually load the correct libraries, or otherwise use the symbols which I've already successfully loaded?

Comment: How we fixed this: https://medium.com/@ephemer/how-we-put-an-app-in-the-android-play-store-using-swift-67bd99573e3c